# Return row Indox of a grid with pagination

Tags: extjs

I have a problem with the rowindex of a grid with pagination.
When I move to page 2, the rowIndox restart with 1 not with the number when he stops in page 1.
I use this to show the number of each line:

```js
{
    header: "#",
    width: 30,
    type:'int',
    align: 'right',
    renderer:function(v, p, r, rowIndex, i, ds){
        return '' + (rowIndex+1)
    }
},
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: the extjs version is 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Use the index of the record as in the following example (starts at 0, therefore add 1):

```
{ header: 'Nr', width: 30, sortable: false, headerId: 'id', renderer: function(value, meta, record){ return record.index+1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the current page from your store and start the rowIndex from there.
Assumin "ds" is your store:

```
renderer: function(v, p, r, rowIndex, i, ds) {
    return '' + ( ds.currentPage*ds.getCount() + rowIndex+1)
}
```

- ds.currentPage is the current page.
- ds.getCount() is the record-limit.

Comment: I find a problem with ds.currentPage: TypeError but ds.getCount() works

Comment: I guess you are using Extjs3. ds.lastOptions or ds.baseParams should contain the current page parameter.

Comment: yes i'm using Extjs3 but i still don't find current page in ds.baseParams